# Web application on a private cloud?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, web-applications

How can I host a web application (Django/Flask) such that its database is in the cloud and only employees of my company can manage it from any location? If not web application what other types of applications should be used to handle all types of devices, ensure company privacy and be in the cloud at the same time?

Comment: Per your comment about not having a corporate network, I recommend also looking into Cloudflare's solutions for securing access to resources on the Internet: https://teams.cloudflare.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer for AWS so I will provide a solution using Google Cloud.

First, you can deploy your application using Google Kubernetes Engine or Google Compute Engine or App Engine.

Second, you need to create an [external HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple) for public access from internet.

Third, you need to set up [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap) to allow only user with Identity allowed to access the application (Google Identities or third party identities)

From my own experiences with AWS and GCP, I found GCP Identity Aware Proxy the easier solution to set up but you will have less control and less options on authentication and authorisation methods.

[image: IAP flow]

Comment: The easiest way is to use AppEngine (compliant with python 3.7 and 2.7 (not recommended)) and IAP. that's all!! Nothing more to set up, to maintain, to update, to oversee, to backup,... It's done for you. Automatically multi zone (for App Engine, deploy replicas for your database). Ridiculously simple compare to AWS!! And I forgot. it's free (for App Engine). Only the database has to be paid

Answer (score 2):

There are likely many architectures for this scenario offered by different cloud providers.

In AWS, for example, you could do this with a **VPC** comprising of a combination of public and private subnets, plus site-to-site VPN access. The web server would be in the public subnet listening on an elastic IP, while the DB would be in the private subnet and connected via **VPN** and a **virtual private gateway** to your corporate site.

It all depends on your specific requirements and constraints.

See just [one of many possible examples:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario3.html)

[image]

For [the various VPN options in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would the above example still hold if I do not have a cooperate network, such that my employees are spread out all over a city or country?

Comment: There are many options. You could set up a  AWS client VPN, which is an endpoint service where remote users can login.You can alternatively install your own VPN server software on an EC2 instance in AWS, and configure it for remote access.